# Openshift Origin 3.6 deleting pod always hangs with finalizers: - foregroundDeletion

Tags: kubernetes, openshift-origin

I'm having a strange issue, when I delete some routes/services/rc/dc/pods, the item hangs on deletion and the item yaml has the following:

```
metadata:
  finalizers:
    - foregroundDeletion
```

If I manually delete:

```
  finalizers:
    - foregroundDeletion
```

Then the item deletes successfully without a problem - is there a way to prevent the finalizers: - foregroundDeletion being added to the item and hanging the deletion thereof ?